# Create new resource from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a link to update a resource:

```
<%= link_to "Cancel", doctor_reservation_cancel_path(reservation.doctor, reservation), method: :put %>
```

That link will update a reservation and set its status to cancel.

```
  def cancel
@reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
respond_to do |format|
  if @reservation.update(:status_id => 4, :canceleddate => DateTime.now)
    format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'Your reservation was succefully canceled.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @reservation }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @reservation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

I would like that link to also create a new resource elsewhere: reimbursement.
That reimbursement will receive the id of the reservation.

How can i do that ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `after_update` callback.

In model, where this `cancel` method is written:

```
after_update :create_new_resource

def create_new_resource
  Reimbursement.create(your_params) if status_changed? && status == 'Cancel'
end
```

Comment: Thx for your help. I added after_update in my model et the def in my controller but it says "undefined method `create_new_resource' for #<Reservation:0x007f805d5876d8>" do you have an idea ?

Comment: @Devlesch, could you please create a gist with the Reservation model? So that I can take a look?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/devlesch/536a009de5a05b73d4ab Do you need something else ?

Comment: It is undefined because you have not add the code of actual method. So except for declaring the after update callback, you have to write the create_new_reinbursement method within the model

Comment: The issue is that you reservation is nil inside method. Prior to pass the reservation into create params, define it. Like reservation = Reservation.find (params [id]) or something like this.